# App armor blocks openoffice Kubuntu 17.10 after update to libreoffice 5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

Tags: updates

```
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.852002] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.360:525): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.853905] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.362:526): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/etc/kde4rc" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.853945] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.362:527): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.856826] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.365:528): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/bin/kdeinit4" pid=3564 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.859263] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.368:529): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.config/Trolltech.conf" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wrc" denied_mask="wrc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.859273] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.368:530): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.config/Trolltech.conf" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.859644] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.368:531): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/lib/kde4/kfilemodule.so" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.859847] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.368:532): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/lib/kde4/kfilemodule.so" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 22 11:00:47 kid kernel: [  880.873476] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293647.382:533): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.config/Trolltech.conf" pid=3552 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wrc" denied_mask="wrc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 22 11:00:54 kid kernel: [  887.608315] kauditd_printk_skb: 84 callbacks suppressed
Feb 22 11:00:54 kid kernel: [  887.608317] audit: type=1400 audit(1519293654.117:618): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/torsten/.kde/share/config/kdebugrc" pid=3567 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Comment: I might have a similar problem but mine works on the root disk.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385549
Try saving to your desktop.

Comment: This seems like a bug. If you can reproduce this issue in a fresh install (VMs are good for this), then please file a bug report using the `ubuntu-bug` application against the `libreoffice` package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005

There is discussion of how to temporarily or permanently deal with apparmor (now part of kubuntu) and it's lack of libreoffice profiles.

I'm still wrestling with it, but this should point you in the right direction.